# Uso e significato dell'espressione "andare a ruba"

Tags: meaning, idioms

Secondo il [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ruba/), l'espressione "andare a ruba" è

> riferita a merci molto richieste che vengono vendute tutte in brevissimo tempo (*il capitone, alla vigilia di Natale, è andato a r. in tutte le pescherie*)

Le definizioni che si trovano in altri dizionari sono simili. Tuttavia, penso di averla sentiro in altri contesti. Per esempio, in qualcosa del tipo

> Questa serie televisiva va proprio a ruba in Italia.

Potreste spiegarmi come e quando si usa questo modo di dire e qual è il suo significato?

Comment: Non ho mai sentito l'espressione "andare a ruba" usata in riferimento ad una serie televisiva e, anche se comprensibile, eviterei di usarla. Andare a ruba si usa per qualcosa che generalmente comperi o richiedi. L'idea è che uno  sarebbe disponibile a "rubare" pur di avere quella cosa. Un tipico esempio sono i nuovi  iphones i quali i primi giorni vanno sempre a ruba.

Comment: @Gio: Io invece l'ho sentita usare così da una persona italiana che parlava della serie *Don Matteo*.

Comment: Può essere, a me suona strana usata in questo senso. Essere italiano  non significa, per definizione,  parlare correttamente. Comunque vediamo come ne pensano anche gli altri. La risposta riportata sotto mi sembra in linea  con quanto detto finora.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il significato è quello che hai già trovato: un'oggetto *va a ruba* se è una merce molto richiesta. Questo significato viene poi utilizzato in modo figurato [1] per indicare un oggetto molto popolare (ad esempio una serie televisiva che tutti guardano).

[1] E, a mio parere, incorretto e fastidioso, ma sappiamo tutti cosa succede a chi cerca di fissare il significato delle parole.

Comment: Ho appena riletto questo e mi sono accorta di non capire il senso dell'ultima frase di questo post. Perché me ne sono resa conto adesso e non tre anni e mezzo fa, non saprei dirlo...